# Dropping a row by index if a value in cell does not equal another value

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop the rows if the 'Year' doesn't equal '1950' in that row.
I am getting "KeyError: 1" error.
Here what I try:

```
import pandas as pd

inpExcelFile = 'den.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(inpExcelFile)
print (df)

for i in range(0,len(df)):

    if df.at[i,'Year'] != '1948':
        df=df.drop(df.index[i])
        print (df)
        df.to_excel('C:/Users/F Yunus Emre Cevahir/Desktop/den2.xlsx')
```

Here is my excel look like:

[image]

Comment: `df.loc[df.Year.eq(1950)]` or something like that

Comment: My method is not good, suggested one worked for me.